# MySQL: How long are binlogs retained?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

I have a mysql slave which I am attempting to replicate a master mysql instance.

I migrated the data a week or so from the production master instance. At the time I invoked `SHOW MASTER STATUS` on the master and got a binlog name and position. Now when I run `SHOW MASTER STATUS` I get:

```
mysql> SHOW MASTER STATUS;
+----------------------------+----------+--------------+------------------+-------------------+
| File                       | Position | Binlog_Do_DB | Binlog_Ignore_DB | Executed_Gtid_Set |
+----------------------------+----------+--------------+------------------+-------------------+
| mysql-bin-changelog.039446 |      120 |              |                  |                   |
+----------------------------+----------+--------------+------------------+-------------------+
1 row in set (0.05 sec)
```

That binlog is not the same one that was there a week ago.

Can I no longer start replication b/c the binlog I am trying to target was rotated? Is there a variable I can check out to see how long I "have" before I can no longer begin replication?

**Edit:**

Also doing some more reading through the mysql docs and I found a command that should list all binary logs:

```
mysql> SHOW BINARY LOGS;
+----------------------------+-----------+
| Log_name                   | File_size |
+----------------------------+-----------+
| mysql-bin-changelog.039456 |       479 |
| mysql-bin-changelog.039457 |       120 |
+----------------------------+-----------+
2 rows in set (0.07 sec)
```

Again the binary log that I wrote down last week is not listed there so my question still remains...

**Edit 2:**

This is AWS RDS specific but I found a stored procedure that lists the rentention hours:

```
mysql> call mysql.rds_show_configuration;
+------------------------+-------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| name                   | value | description                                                                                          |
+------------------------+-------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| binlog retention hours | NULL  | binlog retention hours specifies the duration in hours before binary logs are automatically deleted. |
+------------------------+-------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.06 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.06 sec)
```

[Here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/68272/what-is-default-mysql-binlog-retention-in-aws-rds) it says the binglogs are retained for 24 hours. The database I am trying to replicate takes over 24 hours to migrate meaning by the time it is ready for replication the replication logs it needs to access are already deleted...

**Edit 3:**

Found [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_LogAccess.Concepts.MySQL.html):

> Log File Size
>
> The MySQL slow query log, error log, and the general log file sizes
>   are constrained to no more than 2% of the allocated storage space for
>   a DB instance. To maintain this threshold, logs are automatically
>   rotated every hour and log files older than 24 hours are removed. If
>   the combined log file size exceeds the threshold after removing old
>   log files, then the largest log files are deleted until the log file
>   size no longer exceeds the threshold.

Comment: Might I suggest that you answer this question on http://dba.stackexchange.com/?  Stack Overflow is for programming questions.

Answer (score 14):

For AWS RDS specific instances you can find the retention lengths of binary logs using the following stored procedure:

```
mysql> call mysql.rds_show_configuration;
+------------------------+-------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| name                   | value | description                                                                                          |
+------------------------+-------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| binlog retention hours | NULL  | binlog retention hours specifies the duration in hours before binary logs are automatically deleted. |
+------------------------+-------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.06 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.06 sec)
```

As I am trying to migrate our current MySQL RDS instance to Amazon Aurora I must first migrate the database and then begin replication for any updates that happened during the migration window. Because the migration takes over 24 hours I need to set a longer window than the default 24 window provided by Amazon which apparently I can do with the following [stored procedure](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_LogAccess.Concepts.MySQL.html):

> Amazon RDS normally purges a binary log as soon as possible, but the
>   binary log must still be available on the instance to be accessed by
>   mysqlbinlog. To specify the number of hours for RDS to retain binary
>   logs, use the mysql.rds_set_configuration stored procedure and specify
>   a period with enough time for you to download the logs. After you set
>   the retention period, monitor storage usage for the DB instance to
>   ensure that the retained binary logs do not take up too much storage.
>
> This example sets the retention period to 1 day:

```
call mysql.rds_set_configuration('binlog retention hours', 24);
```

Looks like I need to up the retention time on my master and do another migration, my current one can no longer be properly replicated.